# How to export blender osm to godot so I can use it as a car track?

Tags: graphics, 3d, blender, godot

I'm new to Godot and Blender. I have an assignment where I have to create some kind of driving simulator. I already create the track using blender OSM and export it as .glb and it looks like this: [image]

When I tried to export it to Godot, it turns like it is drowned and the materials are off: [image]

Any advice on how should I do it so I can use the track that I already made on my project at godot? Hope I explain everything well.

Comment: I think you will need to work on the materials on Godot. The advice for exporting models from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68552424/402022) would still apply.  I tried to look for alternatives, and found this: https://github.com/RodZill4/godot-openstreetmap

Comment: Hi, thank you again for answering! Since using OSM in blender is one of the requirement, do you might have some advice for which extension should I go with to export my track? Is it better to export it as .glb or .obj?

Comment: I think glb should be better. Even if the materials come out wrong they would be assigned. Well, there is yet another option you can try: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-blender-exporter It should export from Blender to the Godot scene format.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it